# Non-Linear BVP - ODE - using finite differences

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, finite-element-method, nonlinear-analysis

I have the following ODE

$EI\frac{{{d^2}y}}{{d{x^2}}} = [\frac{{ - qLx}}{2} + \frac{{q{x^2}}}{2}] \cdot {[1 + {(\frac{{dy}}{{dx}})^2}]^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

$\begin{array}{l}
y(0) = 0\\
y(L) = 0
\end{array}$

Using a standard second order discretization of y′′(x) on a grid with uniform spacing the linear system of equations to solve becomes:

\begin{array}{l}
EI\frac{{y(i + 1) - 2 \cdot y(i) + y(i - 1)}}{{{h^2}}} = [\frac{{ - qLx}}{2} + \frac{{q{x^2}}}{2}] \cdot {[1 + {(\frac{{y(i + 1) - y(i - 1)}}{{{h^2}}})^2}]^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\end{array}

I' am not sure how to use Gauss-Seidel method or other method for solving this non-linear ODE using finite differences.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider $y$ an approximation and $y+\delta y$ a closer approximation. Then in first order
\begin{align}
EI(y''+δy'')&=f(x)[1+y'^2+2y'δy'+δy'^2]^{3/2}
\\
&=f(x)\left([1+y'^2]^{3/2}+3[1+y'^2]^{1/2}y'δy'+O(δy'^2)\right)
\end{align}
Ignoring the higher order terms this gives a linear DE for $δy$. Solving this and updating $y$ with the solution constitutes a Newton step, so one can expect rapid convergence (if there is any convergence at all).

Comment: Is there a way to solve this equation without this approximation? I'm searching for a method like Gauss-Seidel or other way

Comment: The linear system for $δy$ is tridiagonal, you can solve it with Gauß-Seidel in every step of the Newton iteration. You can exactly solve the equation for $u=y'$ and then get a first order system that is perhaps easier to discretize.